# Nodejs public folder always fails silently

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to include an icon as part of my website, currently my code looks like the following:

app.js

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const html_file = "./index.html";

var app = express()
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
//app.use(express.static('public'));
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

fs.readFile(html_file, function (err, html)  {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      res.write(html);
      res.end();
    }).listen(port);
console.log(`Listening on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
});
```

While my html file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <body>
<p>test text</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the icon is never loaded properly.
I can see that the request returns in the network inspection tab, and there are no errors from nodejs in the console, but no matter what it fails.

I've tried switching between adding and not including the `/public/` in the link line too, as well as moving the HTML file to the public folder itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, it wasn't failing completely silently. Your request for `favicon.ico` would have been returning the contents of `index.html`.

Comment: Your express server code wasn't hooked to any existing web server so wasn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're starting a vanilla HTTP server that *only* serves your `index.html` file and nothing else.

I'd suggest moving `index.html` into the `public` folder and using `app.listen()` to start your Express app instead.

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I highly recommend working through the Express [*Getting Started*](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) guide.

---

You should also use an absolute path to your icon in the HTML

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```